# Create custom notification including Edit text android

Tags: android, notifications, custom-controls

I wanna create a custom notification to reply SMS directly from notification like this:

[image]

As I have understood normal notifications must have 64dp height but you can use bigger one from API >16 as expandable notification but I think 64dp height is suitable for my case. I used this code but it crashes when my custom notification layout has edit text:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContent(remoteViews);
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
```

Error:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.example.x: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification
```

What should I do?

Comment: "Create custom notification including Edit text android" -- you cannot put an `EditText` in a `RemoteViews`.

Comment: why? what should I do to make that custom notification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Create custom notification including Edit text android

You cannot put an `EditText` widget into a `Notification`, app widget, or anything else that uses `RemoteViews`.

> why?

Because that is how `RemoteViews` is written. You are limited to [certain widgets and containers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

> what should I do to make that custom notification?

Re-design it to not involve an `EditText`.

**UPDATE**: On Android 7.0+, you can use a `MessagingStyle` with `RemoteInput` to accept input from the user from a `Notification`. This does not match the requirements of the question, but it is the closest option.

Comment: Is there any other ways (not Remote viwes) to create custom notification?

Comment: @Mohammad: Not for apps.

Comment: @JakeWilson801: Yes, that is an option for Android 7.0+ devices.

Comment: I'm putting on my resume that @CommonsWare responded to a comment of mine.

Comment: more answers recommeded